# Laravel getPath() not recognized when using route:list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5 and notice something weird going on whenever I do a `php artisan route:list` command via cmd.

It is giving me an error of:
`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to a member function getPath() on a non-object`

The code that it is referring to is this:
`Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()`

But when I dump that code, no errors are being thrown and it is correctly displaying the current route.

No problems too when running a `php artisan serve`. Error is just happening when using the `php artisan route:list` command. Same goes with `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getUri()`

Anybody knows what's going on here?
Thanks so much!

Comment: which file throwing action? you need to give more info to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because when you are in the console the `Route::getCurrentRoute()` returns a `null` value. If you are in a browser, it will return the current route. One solution for this is to check if the current route is not null before retrieving some of its properties:

```
$currentRoute = Route::getCurrentRoute();

if ($currentRoute) 
{
    $path = $currentRoute->>getPath();
}
```